# How to buy an app for a friend?

Tags: applications, paid-apps

I would like to buy a game (well several copies of it really) for some of my friends for Christmas. Is there any way to do this? Would I have to rely on the publisher, or is there some way to "gift" apps from the market?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to currently do this with the Android Market. They're missing a business opportunity here. I can't speak to other app stores, but even if they do have such a feature your friends would need to know how to side-load apk files.

Comment: @Al: I concur, but I think you should add "Buy, send & side load" as an answer because it is a legit way to accomplish what he's asking and as far as I can see its the only way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**: [Google Play Gift Cards](https://play.google.com/intl/en-US_us/about/giftcards/) are now widely available in many countries. Thanks to [@Chahk](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/3646/chahk) for reminding me to update.

Amazon has released their own Android Appstore which allow you to send [Amazon gift cards](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/178-8746537-9249833?ie=UTF8&docId=1000619631) that are redeemable for Android Apps. This requires a few extra steps, but should let you gift what you want to until this function gets added to the original <s>Android Market</s> [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store).

Comment: Gift cards force me to pay 15€ when I want to give away an app for 2€, which is a waste in particular if its not a gift but should rather pass an app to the kids or the partner.