# Gift app on Google Play

Tags: google-play-store

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to buy an app for a friend?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/how-to-buy-an-app-for-a-friend)

I want to gift a Google Play app to some people. For the iOS version I can "gift this app" using iTunes. How can I gift the app to the mail adresses I have got?

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13461/how-to-gift-my-paid-application-to-some-people and http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3163/how-can-i-give-away-a-free-copy-of-my-paid-app

Comment: If this is your app, send him/her apk file.. I think, you've proper distribution right.

Comment: Yes, this is my app. I find sending file unprofessional, certainly with the idea that most "normal" users do not know how to use them. ANy other way? I'll check the links.

Comment: Sorry, this site is only for end users.  You'll have to contact Google for any publishing/developer-account issues.

Comment: @MatthewRead I do not have any publishing/developer-account question, I would have used stackoverflow.com if so. Just because I own the app it doesn't mean I can't wonder how to gift apps (e.g. this app). Its a general question.

Comment: Questions like this are off-topic on [SO] as well. You didn't ask the question generally, you said "I have an app out on Google Play and I want to gift this app to some people."  See the question eldarerathis linked for the general version.

Comment: I could just as well have written "There is an app out on...", yet the question remains the same... how to gift "it" (whomever might own it). Hence, the question is about gifting it... not whom gifts it. Yes, its off-topic on Stack Overflow... hence I wrote it here.. where it is not.

Comment: It's still a duplicate, so I don't understand what the problem is.  If the other question doesn't have an answer to your satisfaction then offer a bounty on it and/or spread the link around so that it will get a better answer.  And stop abusing the flagging functionality.